# Font-awesome icons works only when puts a download link

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

i'm having troubles getting icons from my font-awesome.css file, i need to use my app without a internet conexion, so i need these icons working in a local server, but when i create a new css file and linking it on my template it only shows rare characters like chinesse letters.
It works fine when i put this line:

```
 <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.0.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

What's wrong ?? i'm really confused.

Comment: @KrisRoofe No! He also need the font.

Comment: It's because you are using online link of font awesome. So it will only work when you are online. You need to download font awesome library to run it locally.

Comment: @SidharthGusain which i have to download?? please

Comment: You can download font awesome library from [here](http://fontawesome.io/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

download here: http://fontawesome.io/assets/font-awesome-4.6.3.zip

Copy the css and fonts to your folder.

Then include the css file. Assuming you are working with the index.html

```
<link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```